# Add row to top of AbstractTableModel

Tags: java, swing, jtable, abstracttablemodel

I have a abstractTableModel which I need to add rows to the top, so the user can see the most recent entered data, but default it adds to the bottom of the table. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please show your code!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- override [`public void insertRow(int row, Vector rowData)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html#insertRow%28int,%20java.util.Vector%29)
- this code block must contains proper notifiers [fireTableRowsInserted(int firstRow, int lastRow)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/AbstractTableModel.html#fireTableRowsInserted%28int,%20int%29), otherwise no row is showed in `JTable`s view
- all updates must be done on EDT, more in [Oracle tutorial The Event Dispatch Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html)
- code eamples in Oracle tutorial [How to use Tables - Creating a Table Mode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data)

Answer (score 1):

If the `AbstractTableModel` is using `List` then just while adding the object to the list add it at the zeroth position in the list.

```
list.add(0, object);
```

and call respective `fireXXXMethod`

So now all the objects that are present will move to 1 postion up the list.

Comment: This was the easiest way to do without changing a lot, thx for your reply!